# Shorter output possible - maintaining security properties

Tags: security, hash, digital-signature, truncate

I have a problem that I've been trying to solve for a few days now, but it seems i got stuck!
The problem is, given a piece of data, i need to generate an output that has to be:

- **Impossible for others to reproduce.**
- **Unique.**
- **Short (since it will be used in a URL)**

So i've decided that i would **sign the given data with a private key**, and then **hash the result** - This way i believe the first two properties are covered.
Now, to get the final result as short as possible i started reading and i came across the [THIS](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9435/is-truncating-a-sha512-hash-to-the-first-160-bits-as-secure-as-using-sha1), that talks about truncate a Hash, and i quote

> As far as truncating a hash goes, that's fine. It's explicitly
>   endorsed by the NIST, and there are hash functions in the SHA-2 family
>   that are simple truncated variants of their full brethren:
>   SHA-256/224, SHA-512/224, SHA-512/256, and SHA-512/384, where SHA-x/y
>   denotes a full-length SHA-x truncated to y bits.

After reading a bit more about this, i decided that i would use **SHA256 and truncated it to 128 bits.**
Since it has to be used in a URL, i parsed the final result into a Base62 (Base64 uses `?` and `=` signs which have a different meaning in a URL environment).

The final result was a string with 24 characters, which i thought was good but it seems it's still not good enough.
I need to get it **even shorter (around 10 characters)**. I've been around this for a few days and i am starting to get out of ideas.
Does anyone have any suggestions? Is there something i can try?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does %20 count as 1 or 3 and have you considered truncating SHA-256 to 64 bits?

Comment: It would count as 3 characters...

Comment: How strict is your "unique" criteria @Snox.
In addition i'm guessing that you don't want to store these. Is this for security, performance, or statelessness?

Comment: I've thought about it @Mike but according to NIST, they recommend no less then 112bits. 
Wouldn't that option have a very big collision probability?

Comment: The 'unique' criteria is very strict that is why i can't afford collisions... This is statelessness

Comment: There's no solution for what you want, but from what I can tell you've hit the problem of reaching your maximum URL size. Consider compression on other parts of your URL which take up the majority of the length and use that freed space for a longer hash... Otherwise your implementation sounds fine

Comment: Thank you! I will try compression as a solution... I will give feedback as soon as possible :-)

Comment: The best advice I can give for compression is to look for patterns, not to forget escaping characters. And look for corner cases where you have 20 escape characters in a row.